# How to typeset the 'i' used for imbedding?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

In some books, they use a special 'i' for denoting imbedding of one Sobolev space into a another.

This 'i' is not quite like \imath.
It's like a calligraphic 'i'.

I try to find it with detexify, but it doesn't come out.
It looks like this
[image: imbedding i]

Comment: do you have an image anywhere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately no.

Comment: draw it on paper and upload a pic, you need to give some hint, just saying it doesn't look like \imath leaves the question a bit open;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a pic. I was discourage that detexify couldn't recognize it, and I was afraid to write it myself. Thanks for encouraging me.

Comment: Try `\i`, which removes the dot above a regular `i`.

Comment: It may be helpful to take a picture of the physical symbol you need; as it stands from the picture, `\imath` really does seem like what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd have thought iota as Michael just said, but your drawing looks more like imath to me

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\textit{\i}\imath\iota$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A common notation for imbeddings is the greek `\iota` as in $\iota$. Does it match the symbol you are looking for?